# Plotting Polar Graphs with PGFPlots Using Data from CSV Files

Tags: tikz-pgf, polar

I want to plot a graph in PGF/TikZ using data from CSV files. Below are the link to the CSV file:
https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/3be8309dhs4yspji25zrl/plot3_detailed_ground_shear_pressure.csv?rlkey=npbbqk3t0tfx8frvk5er5ea50&dl=0

[image]

I have tried to create the plots using the following TikZ/PGFPlots code, but I'm encountering some issues. Here's an example of my code for the third plot, "Detailed Ground Shear Pressure:

```
\begin{polaraxis}[
    title={Detailed Ground Shear Pressure},
    legend pos=north west,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,

]

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{plot3_transformed_detailed_ground_shear_pressure.csv}\datatable

\addplot+[no markers] table[x=data_phi_deg, y=Gs] from \datatable;
\addlegendentry{Transformed Gs}

\addplot+[no markers, fill=red, fill opacity=0.3] table[x=data_phi_deg, y expr=\thisrow{Gs}*\thisrow{exceed_mask}] from \datatable;
\addlegendentry{Critical Regions where Gs > Gp}

\addplot+[no markers, fill=orange, fill opacity=0.3] table[x=data_phi_deg, y expr=\thisrow{Gs}*\thisrow{below_mask}] from \datatable;
\addlegendentry{Critical Regions where Gs < -Gp}

\end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Could anyone provide guidance or suggestions on how to correctly plot these graphs in PGF/TikZ using the data from the provided CSV files? I'm looking for advice on whether it's reasonable to pursue this in PGF/TikZ, or if it would be better to stick with Python, given that I've already generated these plots in Python. However, for consistency in my article, I would prefer to use PGF/TikZ to match the style of my other plots. Any insights or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.